# Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be a $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal. Does $\mathfrak{p}^{n} \subset \mathfrak{q} \subset \mathfrak{p}^{n-1}$ for some $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In the setting of Chapter 4 of Atiyah and Macdonald's *Commutative algebra*, an ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ in a commutative ring is **primary** if, $xy \in \mathfrak{q}$ implies either $x \in \mathfrak{q}$ or $y^n \in \mathfrak{q}$ for some $n >0$. If $\mathfrak{q}$ is primary, then its radical $r(\mathfrak{q})$ is prime, and is moreover the smallest prime ideal containing $\mathfrak{q}$. (Conversely, if the radical of $r(\mathfrak{a})$ is maximal, then $\mathfrak{a}$ is primary.)

If $r(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{p}$, we say that $\mathfrak{q}$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary. The authors show by way of example that we need not have $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}^n$, and provide an example in the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$ of a case in which $\mathfrak{p}^2 \subsetneq \mathfrak{q} \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}$.

My question is:

> If $\mathfrak{q}$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary, is it always the case
> that $\mathfrak{q}$ sits between two consecutive powers of
> $\mathfrak{p}$, i.e. we have inclusions $\mathfrak{p}^{n} \subset \mathfrak{q} \subset \mathfrak{p}^{n-1}$ for some $n$? If not, can
> anything be said in general about the relationship between
> $\mathfrak{q}$ and powers of $\mathfrak{p}$?

edit: This is quite a bad question, and its quick to come up with quite extreme counterexamples.

Comment: Have you looked at a single example?

Comment: The ideal $q=(x,y^3)$ is $p=(x,y)$-primary, but there is no $n\ge1$ such that $p^n\subset q\subset p^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Fact: an ideal whose radical is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-primary.

You can take the ring $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ of polynomials in infinitely many variables and $\mathfrak{m}=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$. The ideal $(x_1,x_2^2,x_3^3,\dots,x_i^i,\dots)$ has $\mathfrak{m}$ as radical, hence is $\mathfrak{m}$-primary. However, it contains no power of $\mathfrak{m}$.

In a Noetherian ring you have the primary decomposition. Can you conclude anything?

Comment: Great - thanks for the example! So basically the idea that $\mathfrak{q}$ needs to be `close' to a power of $\mathbf{p}$ in general is about as far from the truth as one can get ;) It's quite obvious in hindsight! Thanks again!

Comment: Related: take $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $\mathfrak q=(x_1,x_2^2,\ldots,x_n^n)$. Then $\mathfrak q$ is $\mathfrak m$-primary, where $\mathfrak m=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a maximal ideal, and satisfies $\mathfrak m^N\subset\mathfrak q\subset\mathfrak m$ for $N=\binom n2$.

Comment: Re the final line: in a Noetherian ring, any primary ideal _is_ sandwiched between 2 powers of its radical, but the powers need not be consecutive